# How to code this with Cplex?

Tags: modeling, cplex

I have an optimization problem as below.

For $g\in G$, let $\mathcal{N}_g$ be the nodes in group $g$, and let binary variable $u_g$ indicate whether group $g$ is used.  The problem has this following constraint

\begin{align}
\sum_{g\in G:\ i\in N_g} u_g &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} 
\end{align}

How can Model this in Cplex?

For example, G=10;

$\mathcal{N}_1={1,2}$

$\mathcal{N}_2={1,3,4}$

$\mathcal{N}_3={1,3,5}$

$\mathcal{N}_4={1,4,5,6}$

...

$\mathcal{N}_{10}={1,6,7,8}$

The only constraint says that every node must be chosen just once.

Here is what I tried so far

```
IloEnv env;
try{

IloNum G=10;

IloNumVarArray Ug(env, G,0,1,ILOINT)

IloModel model(env)
```

In order to make it  efficient for implementation I do a reformulation. I generate a binary matrix,$B$ of size $N_{node}\times G$, where $N_{node}$ is the number of nodes. If node $n, n\in{1,2,\cdots,N_{node}}$ is present in group $g, g\in{1,2,\cdots,G}$, then $B_{n,g}=1$, otherwise 0.

```
IloExpr constFun(env)
```

Note: In Matlab, this constraint now can be expressed as

```
  for n=1:N
      
      sum(Ug(find(B(n,:)==1)))==1;
      
  end
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. That way you can get better answers regarding your specific problem.

Comment: Your set partitioning model is pretty much complete. Is your question "how can I code this with Cplex ?"

Comment: @Kuifje yes. I am not so familiar with Cplex. Especially, the constraint is creating some problem. I do not know how to code this non-symmetric 2D array.

Comment: If you can use [PuLp](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/), such an example is given [here](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/a_set_partitioning_problem.html) (Pulp is just the modeler, you can call CPLEX to solve the problem).

Comment: You seeem to use C++. [Here](https://github.com/fontanf/generalizedassignmentsolver/blob/master/generalizedassignmentsolver/algorithms/milp_cplex.cpp) is a C++ example of an implementation of the Generalized Assignment Problem with Cplex. That's from what I start every time I write a new Cplex model in C++. Maybe it will help you

Comment: @fontanf thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OPL CPLEX you could start with

```
int g=10;
range G=1..g;
range I=1..5;

{int} Ng[G]=[{1,2},{3,4},{5},{},{},
{},{},{},{},{}];

dvar boolean u[G];

subject to
{
  forall(i in I) sum(g in G:i in Ng[g]) u[g]==1;
}
```